# Magento - $_product->getProductUrl() doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, arrays, magento, foreach

I use a foreach loop to loop trough a array with specific products in my 'Magento' store. (3470, 3471, 3472)

This code does seem to work except that the url of every item is the same as the first products url.

When i put one of the id values in the model load example:
$_product = $model->load(3471); the right url is shown.

But when I do this the dynamic way by using the $productid:
$_product = $model->load($productid);
it always returns the first products url by every loop.

Does someone know how to deal with this problem?

**My code:**

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product_ids = array(3470, 3471, 3472);
foreach ($product_ids as $productid){

$_product       = $model->load($productid);
$link_bundel    = $_product->getProductUrl();

$content .= <<<EOF

    <div id="id="bundel-wrapper-{$productid}" class="bundel-wrapper">
        <a id="bundel-link-{$productid}" class="bundel-link" href="{$link_bundel}" title="{$_product->getName()}">
            <img src="{$_product->getImageUrl()}" title="{$_product->getName()}" />
            <div id="specification" class="specification">
                <h2>{$_product->getName()}</h2>
                {$_product->getShortDescription()}
            </div>

        </a>
    </div>

EOF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$product->getUrlPath() instead of $product->getProductUrl()